# Setting background color of xamarin toolbaritems

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, toolbaritems

I'm using Xamarin's ToolbarItems class with XAML:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Sent Messages" Clicked="ToolbarItem_OnClicked" 
    Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Is there a way to change the background color and text color of all the toolbaritems?

Comment: did you found anything about it?

Answer (score 3):

When creating a navigation page you can change the background color, and text color of the `ToolbarItems` as follows.

```
new NavigationPage (new MyPage ()) {
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.Green, BarTextColor = Color.White   
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are nor effect on ToolBarItem text color.